# Lost Private Keys

Tags: private-key, wallet-recovery

I have this old wallet which has funds in it. I was a bit out of business and went out of town. I recently try to create get back but poor me I miss place my credentials lucky I was able to fine my wallet address so I read around I find out there is a way to get my funds back by import it into a new account. I did that it work perfectly but I cant access the funds because I don't have the private keys, so I want to know if there is a way I can do to get back the private keys of the old wallet or how I can transfer the account into the new wallet. thanks

Comment: the whole security of the bitcoin system (and probably many other crypto currencies) is to not be able to derive the private key from the public key. If so, it would make the whole system useless. Unless you have a seed (usually some 12 words) noted down, or the private key in a file (e.g. "wallet.dat"), there is basically no access to your funds. Whatever other sites or sources told you, they are wrong.

Comment: What informations have you backed up? e.g. private key, old wallet, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have the private keys, you will be unable to spend the coins. Knowing a public key or bitcoin address will not allow you to figure out the private keys to an address. The bitcoin blockchain is a public record, so you can look up any address you'd like, but you will not be able to spend the coins they contain unless you know the private key.

You'll need to get access to your wallet, or use a backup of your wallet to be able to spend your coins again.

Comment: that is the issue right now I don't have access to the old wallet, so how do I get the back up of the old wallet @chytrik

Comment: Did you make a backup of the wallet? If you didn't, then it sounds like you're out of luck if you can't access your old wallet. Making backups is important! Sorry for your loss :(

Comment: i don't remember making backup so if I did a back that i will be able to get back the funds. ok who do i do a backup of the new one so i don't run into further trouble

Comment: That's a perfectly valid question. See if it has been asked before here. If not (unlikely) create a new question.